# Cakephp and multiple use of paginate in an action

Tags: php, cakephp, pagination

I have an action in a controller where i use cakedc search with multiple use of pagination in the same action.
in the first pagination i want to use a limit and maxlimit of 50 and in the second one i want to use a limit and maxlimit of 1000.
Here's an example of the code Im using :

```
$this->Paginator->settings['limit'] = 50;
$this->Paginator->settings['maxlimit'] = 50;
$this->set('uuser', $this->paginate());
$this->Paginator->settings['limit'] = 1000;
$this->Paginator->settings['maxlimit'] = 1000;
$this->set('maxusers',$this->paginate());
```

in my page let's say index, Im using only uuser but the problem is it takes the limit and the maxlimit of 1000, instead of 50.
Is there any way to use for uuser variable a limit and maxlimit pagination of 50 and the maxusers a limit and maxlimit pagination of 1000.because the maxusers is stored in session variable and i don't use it in the index.ctp page.

Thanks

Comment: what is your question?

Answer (score 0):

**Here is the example of pagination You add your own custom pagination like this**

```
<div class="paging" style="  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #60C8F2;
    float: right;
    padding: 0 10px;
    text-align: left;
    width: auto;">
<?php
$this->Paginator->options(array(
    'url' => array_merge(array(
        'controller' => $this->params['controller'],
        'action' => $this->params['action'],
    ) , $this->params['pass'], $this->params['named'])
));

echo $this->Paginator->prev('' . '' , array(
    'class' => 'prev',
    'escape' => false
) , null, array(
    'tag' => 'span',
    'escape' => false,
    'class' => 'prev'
)), "\n";
echo $this->Paginator->numbers(array(
    'modulus' => 2,
    'skip' => '',
    'separator' => " \n",
    'before' => null,
    'after' => null,
    'escape' => false
));
echo $this->Paginator->next('' . '', array(
    'class' => 'next',
    'escape' => false
) , null, array(
    'tag' => 'span',
    'escape' => false,
    'class' => 'next'
)), "\n";
?>
</div>
```

**put this code in element pagination.ctp**

**call the component in controller**

```
var $components = array('Paginator');
```

**call the pagination into your controller**

```
 $this->paginate = array(
            'limit' => 10,
            'order' => array(
            'User.created' => 'desc')

        );
        $results = $this->paginate('User');
```

**And in the ctp file call the pagination**

```
<?php echo $this->element('pagination'); ?>
```